# Subversion (svn) update to source tree containing nested checkouts (like clang/llvm)

Tags: svn, nested, clang, llvm, svn-checkout

I've building clang/llvm frequently on various systems following the "Getting Started" instructions (http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html). The SVN folks are really into modularity but don't seem to use the SVN "externals" mechanism, so they require three separate checkouts (llvm, clang, compiler-rt) into a single source tree (with one optional: extra).

Every now and then I build an updated version by doing "svn up" in the source tree root ("llvm") and then rebuilding.

Today, for the first time, I wondered if I should be doing an "svn up" in each separate checkout sub-directory or whether SVN is smart enough to do "recursive updates for nested checkouts". Couldn't find an answer after searching a bit so I am here now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SVN is smart enough to do "recursive updates for nested checkouts"

AFAIK, outside the use of **externals**, SVN is not smart enough to know about nested checkouts.

Comment: Thought of a simple way to verify this. I did "up" in the top-level of an older working copy that was not up-to-date. Several changes applied. Then cd'ed into tools/clang and did "up". Sure enough, many new updates applied (at the same revision level).

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name ".svn" -type d | xargs dirname | xargs svn update
```

Comment: By the way, on MacOS you should replace the middle part with 'xargs -I {} dirname {}'.... That's a letter-I (eye) as the argument